# Conditionals are true but are returning false

Tags: powershell

When debugging, `$var` is not equivalent to "`folder\that\isNot\equivalent\".`

I have tried changing it to an equivalency statement, but it is not working. Any insight would be appreciated.

Here is all the relevant code:

```
$process = "Explorer++.exe"
$var = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = '$process'" | select -expandproperty CommandLine
$var = $var -split '\\\\' | select -Last 1
Write-Host $var
if ($var  -ne "folder\that\isNot\equivalent\")
{
    Stop-Process -processname explorer++
    Stop-Process -processname curProc
}
else
{
    return $true
}
```

Comment: What values are stored in `$var` and `$process` on the `Write-Host` line?

Comment: @Bassie 
When Write-Host executes:
$var = `folder\that\isnot\` as a System.String

`$process = "Explorer++.exe"` also as a System.String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was whitespace surrounding the $var. I used the command `$var = $var -replace "\s",""`

That replaces every space symbol with an empty string, I also changed it to an equivalency statement.

`if ($var  -eq "\folder\that\is\")`

Comment: May be a better idea to use `$var.Trim()` in case the path contains any space